# GDB pointing to the wrong file when debugging with picoprobe + openOCD

Tags: pi-pico, debug

I'm trying to debug a Raspberry Pi Pico project using openOCD + Picoprobe. I go through the steps that appear to be correct to do all this from my Linux PC (the Get started with Pico and C++ guide is for the Raspberry Pi, but there are tutorials online for PC), but when trying to set breakpoints in gdb, it appears to be looking at a different file.
My steps are the following:
In a console, navigate to the openOCD folder and run:
`sudo src/openocd -s tcl/ -f tcl/interface/picoprobe.cfg -f tcl/target/rp2040.cfg`
I get only info messages, no errors, until it waits for the gdb to connect

```
Info : starting gdb server for rp2040.core0 on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
```

Then, in a different console, I navigate to what I want to debug, in this case the blink.c example. I stand inside the build folder with my .elf file and run

```
sudo gdb-multiarch blink.elf

    (gdb) target extended-remote localhost:3333
    (gdb) monitor reset init
    (gdb) break 15
```

where 15 is a relevant debuggable line. But the thing is, the breakpoints are said to be set in a different file:

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x20000178: file ../../../../../../libgcc/config/arm/lib1funcs.S, line 1461
```

and then on, all breakpoints are also set there. Here's an example trying to set 3 different breakpoints:

```
(gdb) b 15
Breakpoint 1 at 0x20000178: file ../../../../../../libgcc/config/arm/lib1funcs.S, line 1461.
(gdb) b 16
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x20000178.
Breakpoint 2 at 0x20000178: file ../../../../../../libgcc/config/arm/lib1funcs.S, line 1461.
(gdb) b 17
Note: breakpoints 1 and 2 also set at pc 0x20000178.
Breakpoint 3 at 0x20000178: file ../../../../../../libgcc/config/arm/lib1funcs.S, line 1461.
```

So that. I am totally lost on what's happening here. Could anyone point me to why this is happening, or what that file does?

Edit: Here's a pastebin of the code, to not clutter the post so much.
https://pastebin.com/pvGni6Fu
Lines 15, 16 and 17 have regular code that should be breakable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the sourcecode where you want to set the breakpoint at line 15. I don't know what `gdb` considers as the file being debugged inthis situation. Assuming the line is in the file that contains the `main` function, I suggest to try something like `break main` `run` `break 15`

Comment: I've added the pastebin. Also, using break main or break main() produces the same line as using a numbered breakpoint, with the same file name.

Comment: This code belongs into the question. Data on external servers may become unavailable. If you use `break main` and then `run`, does it break at the beginning of `main()`?

Comment: No, it never breaks no matter what method I use.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a solution (yet). To make it easier for others, that might be able to help, you should [edit] your question and add all requested information, clarification or code to the question. Comments are for suggestions or to for asking for clarification, not for providing additional information. I suggest to show a [mre] including all commands you use to build and run/debug your program.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add `-g` to your compilation command.

In your project's CmakeLists.txt:

```
add_compile_options(
"$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:-Ofast;-DNDEBUG;-std=c99;-Wall;-Werror;-g>"
)
```

I don't know if there is a more "cmake-conventional" way to add compiler flags.

Creds to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74022330/108802) to your question on stackoverflow.